# SQL*Plus return code when invalid username or password

Tags: sql, oracle, ant, sqlplus

I am trying to develop an ANT script that calls SQL*Plus and executes a SQL file. Using the following:

```
<exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-LOGON"/>
    <arg value="scott/${db.pwdapps}"/>
    <arg value="@${scm.target}/install/sql/XXCUST_COMMON_PKG.pks"/>
</exec>
```

This works but when the username or password is incorrectly supplied, SQL*Plus returns with status of success and hence ANT returns the same.

Anyone know how to make SQLPlus return an error status when the username or password is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sqlplus /nolog
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Apr 14 08:48:07 2011
Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.
SQL> whenever sqlerror exit failure
SQL> connect ronr/wrongpwd
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
echo $?
1
```

Convert the script to use a here document, or have the script to do the connect after setting the sqlerror and pass the connect info as arguments for the script.

Comment: Thanks loads. I managed to solve the problem as there was a typo and it was ignoring the "-LOGIN". Suspect that this was the issue. Your solution looks like it would work too.

Answer (score 2):

A small upgrade to the @ik_zelf proposal.
The solution /nolog works but limit the print of sqlplus, so that if you need logs of the operation performed are not written correctly.

In the man of sqlplus I found the -l parameter that, in case of wrong password, blocks the script, returns error and exit to command prompt:

```
C:\>sqlplus -l test/test@host

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mar Gen 15 15:27:23 20019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle. All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle. Exiting SQL*Plus    
C:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

USERPSW=ronr/wrongpwd

KEY='error'

RETCODE=0

newobjs=$(sqlplus -s << EOF
${USERPSW}
EOF)

if [[ `echo $newobjs | grep -ic "$KEY"` -gt 0 ]]
then
RETCODE=1
else
RETCODE=0
fi